# Fix git-bash files and folders color scheme in Windows Terminal

Tags: bash, themes, git-bash, windows-terminal

Is there some config to make color from file be different from folders?

When I use Git-bash in Windows Terminal, regardless theme, the listed files and folders have the same color, mix them up.

[image: Files and folders listed in Windows Terminal]

I use Git-bash from itself, the files are listed with different color from files.

[image: Same files and folders listed in Git-bash shell]

This is a issue because not all file has a extension.

Answer (score 0):

There is a option for ls command for colorize the output:

```
ls --color
```

To make default, I have created a alias in `~/.bashrc` as follow:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

References:

- [How To Turn On/Off Colors For ls Command In Bash On a Linux/Unix](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-turn-on-or-off-colors-in-bash/?nowprocket=1)
- [How to Change Colors on LS in Bash](https://linuxhint.com/ls_colors_bash/)